# how to use numpy.lexsort without cycles

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Hi I want to order a numpy.array using lexsort.

```
import numpy as np
surnames = ['Hertz', 'Galilei', 'Hertz']
names = ['Heinrich', 'Galilao', 'Gustav']
ind = np.lexsort((names,surnames))
```

But how can I have an array ordered according to this indexes?

I would do

```
surnames2 = surnames.copy()
for i, a in enumerate(ind):
     surnames2[i] = surnames[a]
```

But I think there should be another way without writing the cycle by myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn `surnames` into a numpy array then you can simply index it with the array of integers returned by `lexsort`:

```
sorted_surnames = np.array(surnames)[ind]
```

If you want to stick with plain Python lists, you could do something like this:

```
sorted_surnames = [n for (i, n) in sorted(zip(ind, surnames), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```